# Wordpress, subversion, 2 computers, no work?

Tags: svn, wordpress, xampp, mamp

So we are trying to build a WordPress site with subversion.  My buddy downloads all the information, I can give him my SQL.

Is there any shortcut to making it work between two different computers (he uses a Mac OS so our paths are different by :8888 (on MAMP) and just localhost for XAMPP).

We tried to update the wp_options table so that siteurl and home = "localhost:8888/myproject/wp/"

Nothing seems to work.  We cannot get the WordPress project to show up on his computer.

I was hoping there would be a simple way of doing this so that we can work together at the same time.

Comment: When you say "cannot get the project to show up" what exactly are you seeing or not seeing.  Error messages or detailed description might help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

SVN-Ignore the `wp-config.php` file on both the setups. You can then add a few lines to that file for the `wp_options` that you need to configure for both the sites - add something like:

```
define('WP_SITEURL' , 'http://localhost:8888/myproject/' );
```

Since you will be svn-ignoring this file - you can have as many setups as you want.

A list of parameters is available at: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php